# Unit tests for RestTemplate configuration

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, resttemplate

Is there a way to write unit tests which will test a `RestTemplate` configuration: what are timeouts, what are max numbers of connections etc.?

I have this class and I need to write unit-tests for it.

```
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(() -> {
            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager 
                = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
            connectionManager.setMaxTotal(200);
            connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(100);
            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder
                    .create()
                    .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                            .setConnectTimeout(10000)
                            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(10000)
                            .setSocketTimeout(10000)
                            .build())
                    .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                    .build();
            return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
        }).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can pass in a mock `TemplateBuilder` into the method, then `verify()` that `builder.requestFactory`  was called with an `ArgumentCaptor`, build your template with the factory created from that captor, then verify the template values are correct.

Comment: Thanks @daniu. This could be the way. I will try this out.